# How to map an object with a custom constructor from a dynamic object with automapper

Tags: c#, dynamic, automapper

I'm testing automapper to see if it can do what I need in other project, so I've made some objects in a console project, simplified but that should have what I need:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(List<Banco> bancos)
    {
        this._Bancos = bancos;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public DNI Dni { get; set; }
    private List<Banco> _Bancos;

    public List<Banco> Bancos
    {
        get { return _Bancos; }
    }

}

public class DNI
{
    private DNI() { }
    public DNI(DNI2 letra)
    {
        this._Letra = letra;
        Console.WriteLine("****DNI CONSTRUCTOR****");
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    private DNI2 _Letra;

    public DNI2 Letra
    {
        get { return _Letra; }
    }

}

public class DNI2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DNIId { get; set; }
    public string letra { get; set; }
}

public class Banco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the objects `Person` and `DNI` have a custom cosntructor, and I setted the last one's default parameterless constructor to private.

Now, I need to map nested objects with custom constructors from dynamic objects, so I made this in the same console project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //OJO TODO: ¿Si un objeto dinamico tiene propiedades de varios tipos, es capaz de diferenciar a qué tipo pertenece cada prop?
        //¿qué pasa si un valor del dinamico es del tipo equivocado?
        var bancoConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
        var DNI2Config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
        DNI2Config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var bancoMapper = bancoConfig.CreateMapper();
        var dni2Mapper = DNI2Config.CreateMapper();

        var dni2DBConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes("DNI2");
        });
        var dni2DBMapper = dni2DBConfig.CreateMapper();

        var DNIConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, DNI>()
            .ConstructUsing(dyn => new DNI(dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(dyn)));
            /*.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["Id"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.number, opts => opts.MapFrom<string>(src => (string)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["number"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonId, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["PersonId"]));*/
            /*cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, DNI>()
            .ConstructUsing(dyn => new DNI(dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(dyn as dynamic)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src["Id"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.number, opts => opts.MapFrom<string>(src => (string)(src["number"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonId, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src["PersonId"])));*/

            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        });
        var dniMapper = DNIConfig.CreateMapper();

        dynamic d = new { Id = 0, number = "1234" };
        Banco banco = bancoMapper.Map<Banco>(d);
        Console.WriteLine("Banco: " + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(banco.Id + Environment.NewLine + banco.number);
        Console.ReadLine();

        d = new { Id = 1, DNIId = 0, letra = "a" };
        DNI2 dni2 = dni2Mapper.Map<DNI2>(d);
        Console.WriteLine("DNI2: " + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(dni2.Id + Environment.NewLine + dni2.DNIId + Environment.NewLine + dni2.letra);
        Console.ReadLine();

        d = new { Id = 2, PersonId = 5, number = "5678", DNI2Id = 2, DNIId = 2, letra = "b" };
        DNI2 d2 = dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(d);
        DNI dni = dniMapper.Map<DNI>(d);
        Console.WriteLine("DNI: " + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(dni.Id + Environment.NewLine + dni.PersonId + Environment.NewLine + dni.number + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("dni.dni2: "+dni.Letra.Id + Environment.NewLine + dni.Letra.DNIId + Environment.NewLine + dni.Letra.letra);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

That gives this result in the console:

```
Banco:

0
1234

DNI2:

1
0
a

****DNI CONSTRUCTOR****
DNI:

2
5
5678

dni.dni2: 0
0
```

So, it just creates the `DNI` object and set the members, it go through the public constructor... but even when it goes through the constructor it doesn't set the `DNI2` property.
If I coment the dynamic line in the `DNI` configuration:

```
        var DNIConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, DNI>()
            .ConstructUsing(dyn => new DNI(dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(dyn)));
            /*.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["Id"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.number, opts => opts.MapFrom<string>(src => (string)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["number"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonId, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src as IDictionary<string, object>)["PersonId"]));*/
            /*cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, DNI>()
            .ConstructUsing(dyn => new DNI(dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(dyn as dynamic)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src["Id"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.number, opts => opts.MapFrom<string>(src => (string)(src["number"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonId, opts => opts.MapFrom<int>(src => (int)(src["PersonId"])));*/

            //cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        });
```

... so it does not have the config to make it dynamic, the result is:

```
Banco:

0
1234

DNI2:

1
0
a

****DNI CONSTRUCTOR****
DNI:

0
0


dni.dni2: 2
2
b
```

The commented lines in the configuration is only part of what I've tried, including two days searching here and google.
Seems that the program is telling me: you map it from a dynamic **or** you use custom constructor, you can not do both, suck it.

The most intriguing part for me is: using the first configuration, it isn't mapping the `DNI2` object, but it is mapping the `DNI` object using the constructor(the line is at the console), but it don't have the object needed by the parameters, so it is using the constructor **without the required parameter** O_o
Honestly, I know I'm an amateur and all, but I always thought that even using reflection you couldn't use a constructor(neither any other method) without any of the required parameters.

So: **Is there a way to map a nested object with a custom constructor from a dynamic object with automapper?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this:

```
        var DNIDynConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
        var dniDynMapper = DNIDynConfig.CreateMapper();
        var DNIConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, DNI>()
            .ConstructUsing(dyn => new DNI(dni2DBMapper.Map<DNI2>(dyn)))
            .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
            {
                dniDynMapper.Map(src, dest, typeof(object), typeof(DNI));
            });
        });
```

I don't really like it since it seems that it have to map the object twice, but it works. I would appreaciate if someone came with something better though.